# Sublime Text 3 in Cmder - How do I launch Sublime and move the terminal to the left or top side of the screen?

Tags: split, sublimetext3, alias, pane, cmder

In Cmder, it is possible to configure and launch Sublime Text 3 using aliases located in the following directory "%CMDER_ROOT%/config/user_aliases.bat".

Referring to the source: [Seamless-Sublime-Text-3-Integration](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-Sublime-Text-3-Integration), It states how to split the screen in the Cmder Terminal using `-new_console:s50V` or `-new_console:s50H`.

However, if we would like to start Sublime console in Top or Left side of the screen, then we have to approach things differently. How to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have set the following virtual environment variables - %CMDER_ROOT% and %ConEmuDir%.
2. Make sure that you have already installed and configured Sublime Text 3 for Cmder.
3. Open "%CMDER_ROOT%/config/user_aliases.bat" in the preferred editor.
4. Include the following aliases at the new line

   `subl_left="%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $* -new_console:s75H $t cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%..\init.bat" $* -new_console:s25H $t exit`

   `subl_top="%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $* -new_console:s75V $t cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%..\init.bat" $* -new_console:s25V $t exit`

5. Restart Cmder.exe and check if everything is working by calling the newly defined aliases in the terminal `subl_top` or `subl_left`.

---

`"%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $* -new_console:s`

Includes Sublime Text 3 in the terminal.

`$t cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" $* -new_console:s`

Creates new terminal.

`$t exit` Kills the first terminal which launched the previous two commands.